# How do I change my code to fit a wider variety of strings?

Tags: java, string

I'm sorry my title doesn't make much sense but I am trying to replace substrings in a word, with a single character, and vice versa. For example, "the" matches with "&", "an" matches with "~", "ion" matches with "#", "ing" matches with "@", "tis" matches with "%", "men" matches with "+", and "re" matches with "$". Another example, "Thank you" -> "Th~k you" AND "Th~nk you" -> "Thank you".

This is kind of a personal project and I am making it a little hard on myself so I cannot use .replace(), .replaceAll(), or .replaceFirst().

Once given an input file and output file, the program passes the input file to a processFile method that takes the next line in the file and passes it to a compressLine method, which then passes it to a compressWord or decompressWord method (depending on user options), then sends the output file.

I have tried to use a for loop to iterate over each character of the word but it doesn't really work with multiple character sequences. Currently, my while loop is set for a string with spaces and not a word. So if I try to duplicate and adjust to find other strings, it prints out garbage. Also, the code is only set for the first target word and the first replacement word at index 0. The list is in order with each index of targetWord matching to same index in replacementWord

Attached is the compressWord and decompressWord method. I haven't completed the decompressWord method but it should be fairly similar to the compressWord method.

```
//Returns string containing compressed word (token)
//Throws an IllegalArgumentException with the message, "Null word", if word is null
    public static String compressWord(String word) {
        if (word == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null word");
        }

        String[] targetWord = {"the","an","ion","ing","tis","men","re"}; 
        String[] replacementWord = {"&","~","#","@","%","+","$"}; 
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
 
        int i = 0; 
    
        while (i < word.length()) {
            // Find the next occurrence of the target word 
            int start = word.indexOf(targetWord[0], i); 
     
            // If the target word is not found, append rest of the string and exit the loop 
            if (start == -1) { 
                stringBuilder.append(word.substring(i)); 
                break; 
            } 
     
            // Append the part of the string before the target word and the replacement word 
            stringBuilder.append(word.substring(i, start)); 
            stringBuilder.append(replacementWord[0]); 
     
            // Update the index to start searching for the next occurrence after the end of the replaced word 
            i = start + targetWord[0].length();
        }
 
        String replacedString = stringBuilder.toString(); 
        return replacedString;
        
    }

    //Returns string containing decompressed word (token)
    //
    //Throws an IllegalArgumentException with the message, "Null word", if word is null

    public static String decompressWord(String word) {
        if (word == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null word");
        }
        
        //TO DO

        return word;
    }
```

Please let me know if I need to provide additional information and I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: to make all the changes in a loop you need to iterate over the target words. After each replacement has been done you should replace `word` with the contents of the `StringBuilder` object, and repeat the replace process for the nex target word.

Answer (score 1):

To tackle your project effectively and address the limitations you've encountered with your compressWord method and the yet-to-be-completed decompressWord method, we'll need to make some adjustments. The key is to generalize your approach so that it can handle all mappings in both the compression and decompression processes, without relying on restricted methods like .replace().

Let's refine your methods to iterate over all the mappings you've provided, ensuring that both compression and decompression work seamlessly for any given input. This approach will involve searching for all target substrings (for compression) or replacement characters (for decompression) in the input string and replacing them accordingly. Since you've encountered issues with handling multiple characters and maintaining index consistency, we'll carefully manage indices to address these concerns.

**General Approach**

1. **Iterate Through Mappings**: Instead of focusing on a single mapping at
   a time, we'll loop through all mappings for each pass through the
   string.
2. **Index Management**: We'll carefully update indices as we go to
   avoid problems with overlapping or missing replacements.
3. *StringBuilder for Efficiency*: Continue using StringBuilder to build
   the result efficiently.

**Refined Compression Method**

The compression method you provided works for a single mapping. Let's extend it to handle all mappings:

```
public static String compressWord(String word) {
    if (word == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null word");
    }

    String[] targetWords = {"the", "an", "ion", "ing", "tis", "men", "re"};
    String[] replacementWords = {"&", "~", "#", "@", "%", "+", "$"};
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < targetWords.length; i++) {
        int index = stringBuilder.indexOf(targetWords[i]);
        while (index != -1) {
            stringBuilder.replace(index, index + targetWords[i].length(), replacementWords[i]);
            index = stringBuilder.indexOf(targetWords[i], index + replacementWords[i].length());
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

**Decompression Method**

For decompression, you'll reverse the process. Since replacement characters are single characters, you can directly search for them and replace them with their corresponding target words:

```
public static String decompressWord(String word) {
    if (word == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null word");
    }

    String[] targetWords = {"the", "an", "ion", "ing", "tis", "men", "re"};
    String[] replacementWords = {"&", "~", "#", "@", "%", "+", "$"};
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(word);

    for (int i = 0; i < replacementWords.length; i++) {
        int index = stringBuilder.indexOf(replacementWords[i]);
        while (index != -1) {
            stringBuilder.replace(index, index + replacementWords[i].length(), targetWords[i]);
            index = stringBuilder.indexOf(replacementWords[i], index + targetWords[i].length());
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

**Key Notes**

- **Efficiency**: This approach is designed to be efficient and general enough to handle any mapping from your lists, addressing the complexity of handling multiple character sequences.
- **Flexibility**: The methods are flexible and can easily be adjusted for additional mappings or changes in the compression/decompression logic.
- **Testing**: Ensure thorough testing with edge cases, such as strings that contain sequences of replacement characters or target words back-to-back, to verify that the logic handles all scenarios correctly.

Comment: which might not be the most efficient approach for very long strings or a large number of substitutions

Comment: Thank you for your help but I cannot use the .replace() method. You used it towards the end of your code. This was one of the main problems I was having. Is there another way to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Aho-Corasick Algorithm**

**Aho-Corasick Algorithm Overview**

**Build the Trie**: First, construct a trie from all target words. Each node represents a character, and each path from the root to a leaf represents a target word.

**Failure Links**: Add failure links to each node. A failure link of a node is a pointer to the longest proper suffix of the string from the root to this node that is also a prefix of another pattern. This allows the algorithm to efficiently handle mismatches by jumping to other potential matches without re-scanning characters.

**Output Links**: For nodes that represent the end of a target word, add output links that point to other nodes that are also ends of target words and are suffixes of the current word. This is used to find all pattern matches at a given position in the text.

**Search Phase**: Traverse the input text, following the trie based on the current input character and the failure links when mismatches occur. Use output links to report all matches.

```
class TrieNode {
    Map<Character, TrieNode> children = new HashMap<>();
    boolean isEndOfWord = false;
    // For simplicity, we directly store the replacement string here. In a full implementation,
    // you'd also have failure and output links.
    String replacement = "";

    void insert(String word, String replacement) {
        TrieNode current = this;
        for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
            current = current.children.computeIfAbsent(ch, k -> new TrieNode());
        }
        current.isEndOfWord = true;
        current.replacement = replacement;
    }
}
```

---

```
// Assume we have a method to build the trie with failure and output links
// For simplicity, this example will not implement those parts.

public static String compressUsingAhoCorasick(String text, String[] targetWords, String[] replacements) {
    TrieNode root = new TrieNode();
    for (int i = 0; i < targetWords.length; i++) {
        root.insert(targetWords[i], replacements[i]);
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    TrieNode current = root;
    // This loop simulates the traversal of the text, but without failure and output links,
    // it's not fully implementing the Aho-Corasick search.
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ) {
        if (current.children.containsKey(text.charAt(i))) {
            current = current.children.get(text.charAt(i));
            if (current.isEndOfWord) {
                // A match is found, append replacement
                result.append(current.replacement);
                // Reset to start state
                current = root;
                // Skip ahead by the length of the matched pattern, this needs adjustment
                // to handle overlaps and multiple matches correctly with output links
                i++; // Placeholder, should jump by word length
            } else {
                // Continue with the next character if not at an end of word
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            // If no match, append the current character and try again from root
            // This logic is overly simplistic and needs failure links to properly handle mismatches
            result.append(text.charAt(i));
            i++;
            current = root; // Reset to start state
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

To fully implement the Aho-Corasick algorithm, you would need to:

Implement failure and output links for each node in the trie.
Adjust the search phase to utilize these links for efficiently handling mismatches and reporting all matches.